# Why can I apt-get install rapidsvn but not see it within the Ubuntu Software Center GUI?

Tags: 18.04, software-center

I went to install Rapid SVN from the Ubuntu Software Center today as I have done before - it wasn't there.

I can install this using the command:

`sudo apt-get install rapidsvn`

Why can I apt-get install rapidsvn but not see it within the Ubuntu Software Center GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Software Center is focused on end-user applications and indeed will not "find" many individual packages. There is a [bug report on this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1568056)

Obviously, this requires you to use the terminal to find and install specific packages. You also may use the powerful Synaptic Package Manager to be able to manage your installed software at the level of the individual installation packages.